# How to create a funnel chart with svg

Tags: svg, charts

I'm trying to create an funnel chart like this with svg. https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUyru.jpg

My first attempt was with svg filter effects, but then I found out that svg filter effects aren't supported in IE.

The second attempt was with svg paths but I can't manage to transform the path based on the previous circle.

http://codepen.io/justpixel/pen/MwOLRQ

`<path transform="translate(0 27) scale(0.9 0.6)" fill="#ED1C24" d="M240.208,110.922c-43.5-29-140.417,19.125-175.322,19.125V0c34.906,0,131.822,50.422,175.333,18.667
    L240.208,110.922z"/>`

Do you have any tips on how can I do this?

Comment: IE 10 and IE 11 support SVG filters: http://caniuse.com/#search=SVG%20Filters

Comment: Thanks for the link. Didn't know that. 
Probably the article where I read was outdated. I'll try to play with svg filters parameters to obtain some similar results.

Comment: You don't say whether you intend to pre-generate the graphs, or have them generated in-browser.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I want them generated in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple. as long as you know how to create SVG elements with JS - and you know a little bit of trigonometry.

```js
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

// Make the graph
var radius = [88, 66, 56, 27];
var inter_circle_gap = 80;
var startX = 120;
var startY = 120;
var funnelSqueezeFactor = 0.3;

// Draw the funnels
var g = document.getElementById("funnels");
var x = startX;  // centre of first circle
var numFunnels = radius.length - 1;
for (var i=0; i<numFunnels; i++)
{
    nextX = x + radius[i] + inter_circle_gap + radius[i+1];
    makeFunnel(g, x, nextX, startY, radius[i], radius[i+1]);
    x = nextX;
}

// Draw the circles
var g = document.getElementById("circles");
var x = startX - radius[0];  // left edge of first circle
for (var i=0; i<radius.length; i++)
{
    x += radius[i];  // centre X for this circle
    makeCircle(g, x, startY, radius[i]);
    x += radius[i] + inter_circle_gap;  // step to left edge of next circle
}


// Function to make a circle
function makeCircle(g, x, y, r)
{
    var circle = document.createElementNS(svgns, "circle");
    circle.setAttribute("cx", x);
    circle.setAttribute("cy", y);
    circle.setAttribute("r", r);
    g.appendChild(circle);
}

// Function to make a funnel
function makeFunnel(g, x1, x2, y, r1, r2)
{
    var tangentAngle = 30 * Math.PI / 180;;  // 30 degrees
    startPointX = r1 * Math.sin(tangentAngle);
    startPointY = r1 * Math.cos(tangentAngle);
    endPointX = r2 * Math.sin(tangentAngle);
    endPointY = r2 * Math.cos(tangentAngle);
    ctrlPointX = (x1 + x2) / 2;
    ctrlPointY = (startPointY + endPointY) * funnelSqueezeFactor / 2;
    var d = 'M' + (x1 + startPointX) + ',' + (y - startPointY);
    d += ' Q' + ctrlPointX + ',' + (y - ctrlPointY) + ','
              + (x2 - endPointX) + ',' + (y - endPointY);
    d += ' L' + (x2 - endPointX) + ',' + (y + endPointY);
    d += ' Q' + ctrlPointX + ',' + (y + ctrlPointY) + ','
              + (x1 + startPointX) + ',' + (y + startPointY);
    d += "Z";
    var path = document.createElementNS(svgns, "path");
    path.setAttribute("d", d);
    g.appendChild(path);
}
```

```css
#circles circle {
    fill: #27293d;
}

#funnels path {
    fill: #f5d135;
}
```

```html
<svg width="779px" height="306px">
    <g id="funnels"></g>
    <g id="circles"></g>
</svg>
```